# How does Spring mange websocket connections to RabbitMQ?

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-websocket

I have a game server that uses websocket for real time multiplayers. It is a Spring 4 application and I use RabbitMQ as my broker. This is my configuration:

```
<websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/app">
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/portfolio">
        <websocket:sockjs/>
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
    <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/queue, /topic"/>
</websocket:message-broker>
```

From a very small test with 4 clients I saw 4 connections open on Rabbit.

Does each client that connects to my server using websocket eventually open a new connection to the broker (RabbitMQ)? Can this be configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, each websocket client gets its own TCP connection to the broker. The documentation has a section for [connections to the broker](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-handle-broker-relay-configure) (emphasis mine):

> A STOMP broker relay maintains a single "system" TCP connection to the broker. This connection is used for messages originating from the server-side application only, not for receiving messages. [...]
>
> **The STOMP broker relay also creates a separate TCP connection for every connected WebSocket client**. [ ... ]

If this can be configured or not I don't know, I'm not all that familiar with this part of Spring, but I assume it should be; Spring is open to extension. My suggestion is to post an issue on the [spring-websocket-portfolio](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio) project and ask for specifics.

**EDIT :** OP opened the following [issue](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio/issues/48) on the spring-websocket-portfolio project.